# How to keep a door from closing when left open

Tags: doors, closer, magnet

I have a bathroom door that naturally tends to close itself if left open. I would like to not replace or rehang the door (it is a cheap hollow-core door, but I would like to add … something so that the door stays all the way open when left open, but can still be closed (and only stay closed if the latch is engaged). It would be preferable if the door would swing open when left partially open. Also, since other people are involved, it cannot be something that has to be ‘done’ every time. My current ’solution’ is for me, and only me, to notice the door has swung shut and go over and drape a towel off the towel rack over th door knob

(The room is the first room off th furnace/AC, so if the door is closed, that room gets either very hot or very cold). If it matters, the basement dates from the early 1960s, and the room is a very small half-bath (about 5’x5’).

A closure with a ‘keep open’ setting or a door stop with a magnetic latch will only keep the door open if it is intentionally pushed all the way back, and I basically want the opposite, for the door to be opened unless it is actually latched closed.

Comment: A door that is plumbed, levelled and balance should stay in place, closed open fully or open halfway.  Wind/drafts will mess this up.  Check if the door is plumb by it's hinge side, and check it's level along the top.

Comment: I agree with crip as it may be perfectly hung and the furnace / AC draft could be pushing it closed. There are spring hinges that can be added to keep a door opened or closed simple replacement can be the solution and turn the tension down so it feels natural. Or adding a slight offset to the top and bottom hinges to hang it out of true so it will swing open can be as simple as pulling the screws putting tooth picks in and replace screws at the bottom the left side of the tooth pick right side at top this slight shift could do it

Comment: Take the door closer idea and install it on the other side of the door, that will keep it open.

Comment: While this isn't for everyone, it works great (silent, reliable, cheap) for me and my cats. Get two small eye-hooks or cup hooks. Open the door fully against the wall. Screw one hook at the top of the door, handle-side. Screw the other into the wall close to the door's hook. Tie a string to the wall hook. Feed the string though the door's hook. Add a small weight to the end of the string, i used a decorative horseshoe. You can flip script and attach to the jamb to keep it closed in the same way.

Comment: See: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/242586/18078

Comment: XY problem. The issue you're trying to fix: "The room is the first room off th furnace/AC, so if the door is closed, that room gets either very hot or very cold" would surely best be resolved by adjusting the flow of conditioned air into the room such that it doesn't matter whether the door is open or shut, rather than having to keep the door open ... ?

Comment: The vent in the room is completely closed, and still that tiny room gets completely out of whack with the rest of the house. Sorunbg hinges are probably the best solution, but I am going to ty a magnetic doorstop first and see if I can train the other people in the house to at least push the door open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a crude suggestion, but it's worked for me:  Take one of the hinge pins out, put on a safe surface and very carefully hit it with a hammer to very slightly bend it. The added friction might keep the door open. Go slowly and test often. Use a sharpie to mark which side of the pin to hammer on just a tiny bit more as you test, test, test.

Another approach is to get much longer screws for the top hinge, remove the existing screws and install the new, longer screws (into the wall opening of course), sometimes that can pull the jamb in just enough to make the door behave.

Answer (score 0):

There are virtually dozens of door stoppers types.

Some more fancy than others.

Many you have to step on to activate door stop.

Some use magnet, convenient, no need to do anything to stop the door.

[image: magnet]

And very simple one. You do not have to do anything to stop the door. You will have to lift it (with your foot) to close the door.

[image: stopper]

Source: Walmart

Comment: Good for most doors, but sometimes an inconvenience if you are in hurry to close the bathroom door.  It happens.

Comment: @crip659 are you talking about emergency

Comment: The kind where you wait too long to go.