Which door hinge pin should I bend?
The door in a bathroom keeps swinging open regardless of the position it's left in. I searched Home Improvement for a solution and this answer said to bend a pin from one of the hinges, which seemed like a reasonable option. https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/252524/181218.
Does it matter from which hinge I pull the pin to bend? If so, which one should I bend?
I added pics of all three hinges. The first two pics are both of the top hinge.
I don't have a good level. I used the level app on my phone and another phone and I've put the phones on top of the door, up by the small edge of the door, and against the main side with the door. I had the door open and almost closed for all those sides. None of those positions indicated anything other than 0 degrees.





do not bend any pins, it is a bad suggestion.

Pictures of all the hinges would help.

Do not bend hinge pins; relocate the hinge on the door frame to make the door vertical.

It’s true that bending is a hack and that it’s far better to fix the underlying issue. If you must bend a hinge, any will do, though I’d choose the top for ease of access.

The door is not plumb and/or level.  You check for plumb and level, and then move the hinge/s to fix.

That can happen when hinges are not at equal depth in the frame.
unscrew the upper hinge, insert one or two screw washers where the screw fits easily true, and screw the hinge back on with washers under the hinge – as spacers
That should give the door enough tilt too close.
If not try with the lover hinge

Packing the hinges usually changes how the door edges meet the jamb, and won’t correct what is probably the underlying issue of plumb in plane with the wall.
